# Display text depending on a choice made in select box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I run a PHP query which only runs when an option is chosen from a select dropdown but also which refreshes each time a different option is chosen?

For example, here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/hr/includes/jui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select_box_1').change(function() {
       if($(this).val() != '')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'balance1.php',
            data: 'value' + $(this).val() ,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result-div").html(data);
            }
        });
     }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="validate.php">

<div id="select_box_1">
<select name="drop_down">
<option value="">Please choose</option>
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Bob</option>
<option value="3">Mike</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="result-div">

</div>

<input type="submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

balance1.php

```
<?php 
print "GET Value:".$_GET['value'];
?>
```

I would like to run a query below the select box depending on the value chosen - for example, when nothing is chosen there is no query ran. If the user chooses John from the list then the query runs where the id=1 and displays results for John. If the user then chooses Bob, the query should run again where the id=2 and so on?

Comment: Use AJAX (`.ajax()` or `.get()` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

```
[...]
<select name="drop_down" id="sel_something">
[...]

$('#sel_something').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'someurl',
            data: { 'value' : $(this).val() } ,
            success: function(data) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I gave an id to the select and modified the data line (and added a few syntax corrections).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use jquery.ajax, which is way more powerful than you think mate ! below is the example code to make it working

```
$('#select_box_1').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() != '')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'URL To Your PHP Script',
        data: 'value' + $(this).val() ,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result-div").html(data);
        }
    });
 }
});
```

**EDIT :** `$_GET['value']` will hold the value in your php script, you can query database using that value and return your result or output to ajax call and then you can simply populate the data in your html view

Comment: Thank you for this - within the PHP script called by url how can I access the value from the select box? i.e. "select name from database where id=1" when John is chosen, or "select name from database where id=2" when Bob is chosen?

Comment: Doesn't do anything now :( Before the edit it displayed the contents of the included php file but didn't carry through value so I couldn't do a select but now when I choose a name from the drop down nothing happens at all unfortunately. When I remove the if statement it "works" in that it displays the contents of the php file so it would appear that the option value from the select is not getting picked up

Comment: kindly paste your php script in your question aswell, let me see !

Comment: The scripts are VAST so to simplify things I tried it with a script just containing <?php print $_GET['value'];?> and still nothing happens - I have edited my original to include the whole HTML, the PHP file literally only has the one print GET line now

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#select_box_1").change(function(){

    if ($(this).val() != "") {

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "foo.php",
         data: "id=" + $("#select_box_1").val(),
         success: function(msg){
           $("#result").text(msg);
         }
      });

    }

});
```

Comment: in your if condition you could do like this `if($(this).val())` because `$(this).val()` is actually holding DOM. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the page everytime the value is changes in the dropdown, then you can use onchange attribute in your SELECT tag.

Reload the page when value is changed and set a GET variable in the URL. If this GET variable is NULL then do not process the PHP code ... else process accordingly.

Comment: I am not reloading the page each time - the only thing which will change is the value in the select box until the form is submitted

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was just asking if you are ok with the page reload.
When the value in the dropdown changes  the reload function in "onchange" attribute will cause the page to reload and the php script to process again.
I you want to do it without the page reload then you can always use Ajax.